# React - how to set initial state from URL parameters with React Router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state

I am passing an ID in URL like so:

```
<Link title="Open goal" to={"/app/goal/id"+key}>Open goal</Link>
```

**And the route is working perfect** (*/app/goal/id-Kho8lGjYN31WiYwgthE*):

```
<Route path="/app/goal/id:goalId" component={GoalView} />
```

I just want to get the `goalId` from the URL in a component class constructor to set it as a state. I just don't know what is thy right syntax to do so.

**I was trying something like:**

```js
class GoalView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataGoal: {},
      currentGoalId: this.props.match.params.goalId,
    };
  }
  
  ...
  
}
```

but that doesn't work ending in a `ReferenceError: match is not defined`.

Any ideas how can I get the `goalId` from the URL?

Thanks for any help,
Jakub

> I am so sorry... I have figured it out. I had an error on a totally
>   different row. It is working just fine.